# How to use collection_select to adjust my form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use collection_select to solve this problem:

Users can create a case and should be able to select a diagnosis. So I created a scaffold for Diagnosis including illness:string to create diagnosis.
After that I did a migration with "AddDiagnosisToCase" which look like this:

```
class AddDiagnosisToCase < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :cases, :diagnosis, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Now I'm trying to adjust my **_form.html.erb** to add a select, where all the diagnoses appear, which we created earlier.

Unfortunately that didn't worked, because I did it the wrong way:

```
<%= form_for @case do |form| %>

...

<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :diagnosis %>
    <%= form.collection_select :diagnosis, :case_id, Diagnosis.all, :id, :name, :promt => true %>
  </div>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your migration, you have to set diagnosis_id to case. Below code should work for you

```
<%= form_for @case do |form| %>

...

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :diagnosis %>
    <%= form.collection_select :diagnosis_id, Diagnosis.all, :id, :illness, :prompt => true %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it. Unfortunately got that error: 

NoMethodError in Cases#new
Showing ... where line #41 raised:

undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol

Comment: What columns diagnosis table have? Looks like diagnosis table does not have name columns.

Comment: This is the table for diagnosis:  `create_table "diagnoses", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|     t.string "illness"     t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false     t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false   end`

Comment: do we want show `illness` in select dropdown?

Comment: @Cookieholik I have updated the answer, Could you please check now?

Comment: Yes, we do want to show `illness` in select dropdown.

Comment: Tried the updated answer, same error: undefined method `merge' for :illness:Symbol . :(

Comment: Could you please try now?